# Ijkplayer error

Tags: android, android-ndk, streaming

Good evening, I'm trying to run the library ijkplayer Android, I followed the guide from GIUTHUB but when I start the app gives me this error:

```
03-24 21:20:54.645  18480-18480/tv.danmaku.ijk.media.demo E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: tv.danmaku.ijk.media.demo, PID: 18480
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load ijkffmpeg from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/tv.danmaku.ijk.media.demo-13.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/tv.danmaku.ijk.media.demo-13, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
            at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:358)
            at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
            at tv.danmaku.ijk.media.player.IjkMediaPlayer$1.loadLibrary(IjkMediaPlayer.java:98)
            at tv.danmaku.ijk.media.player.IjkMediaPlayer.loadLibrariesOnce(IjkMediaPlayer.java:106)
            at tv.danmaku.ijk.media.player.IjkMediaPlayer.initPlayer(IjkMediaPlayer.java:147)
            at tv.danmaku.ijk.media.player.IjkMediaPlayer.<init>(IjkMediaPlayer.java:143)
            at tv.danmaku.ijk.media.player.IjkMediaPlayer.<init>(IjkMediaPlayer.java:135)
            at tv.danmaku.ijk.media.widget.VideoView.openVideo(VideoView.java:249)
            at tv.danmaku.ijk.media.widget.VideoView.access$2300(VideoView.java:61)
            at tv.danmaku.ijk.media.widget.VideoView$8.surfaceCreated(VideoView.java:513)
            at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:601)
            at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:94)
            at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:184)
            at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:895)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2263)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1297)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6773)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:813)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:613)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:583)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:799)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5748)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am using Android Studio 1.1.0 on MAC OSX

This is my build.gradle -> ijkdemo

```
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile FileTree (dir: 'libs', includes: '* .jar')
    compile project (': ijkmediawidget')
    compile project (': ijkmediaplayer')
    compile project (': ijkmediawidget')
    compile project (': ijkmediaplayer')
}

Android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"


    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests / java, tests / res, etc ...
        instrumentTest.setRoot ('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types / <type>
        // For instance, build-types / debug / java, build-types / debug / AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src / <type> / ... which would
        // Conflict with src / being used by the main source in September
        // Adding new build product types or flavors Should be accompanied
        // By a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot ('build-types / debug')
        release.setRoot ('build-types / release')
    }
}
```

I set the ANDROID NDK file local.properties
ndk.dir = /Users/user/Documents/ndk

Comment: Could you elaborate more on this question, there seems to be much data and so little context.

Comment: if you've followed the guide, it should work. Can you list the files that are inside the APK you've generated ? Are there .so files inside `lib/<abi>` ? Which version of the NDK are you using ? `./compile-ffmpeg.sh` and `./compile-ijk.sh` did run properly ?